# Databinding 2 comboboxes Issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, viewmodel

I have 2 comboboxes. If i select a Activity in the 1st one, the related sub activities should be displayed in the second combobox.
The code looks fine as per MVVM style but when i select an activity on 1st one, the related subactivities in the 2nd combobox are not synched.
Here is my code:
**View**

```
<Window x:Class="TestDGCombosBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDGCombosBinding"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ActivitiesDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Activities}" MethodName="GetActivities"/>
        <local:DebugConverter x:Key="DebugConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid 
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"                     
                 SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                 SelectionMode="Single"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                 RowBackground="White" 
                 AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"                                          
                 AlternationCount="2" Name="dataGrid1" CurrentCellChanged="dataGrid1_CurrentCellChanged">
        <DataGrid.BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup />
        </DataGrid.BindingGroup>
        <DataGrid.Resources>

        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Activities Custom" CanUserSort="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Text="{Binding CurrentActivity}"                                       
                                    SelectedValuePath="ActivityID"                                        
                                    DisplayMemberPath="ActivityName"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ActivitiesDataProvider}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SubActivities Custom" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Text="{Binding CurrentSubActivity}"                                       
                                    SelectedValuePath="SubActivityID"                                      
                                    DisplayMemberPath="SubActivityname"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubActivitiesOfCurrentActivity}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

---

**Model**

```
public class Activities
{
    public DataView GetActivities()
    {
        return ActivitiesAccess.GetAllActivities();
    }
}
```

---

**ViewModel**

```
public class ActivitiesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ActivitiesViewModel()
    { }
    private int currentActivity;

    public int CurrentActivity
    {
        get { return currentActivity; }
        set { 
                currentActivity = value;
                SubActivitiesOfCurrentActivity = ActivitiesAccess.GetAllSubActivitiesinActivity(currentActivity);
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentActivity");
            }
    }

    private DataView subActivitiesOfCurrentActivity;

    public DataView SubActivitiesOfCurrentActivity
    {
        get {return subActivitiesOfCurrentActivity; }
        set
        {
            subActivitiesOfCurrentActivity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SubActivitiesOfCurrentActivity");
        }
    }

    private int currentSubActivity;

    public int CurrentSubActivity
    {
        get { return currentSubActivity; }
        set
        {
            currentSubActivity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSubActivity");
            }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

---

When i debug the code when i select an activity from the 1st drop down, the CurrentActivity property value is always 0 which im not sure why.
This value should be equal to the ActivityID of the selected activity.
I searched alot to get help but i couldnt find anything.
I will be very happy if someone could specify any problem in the code.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a while as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue.
When An Activity is Changed, the related Sub-Activities should be notified of the change.
But when the Sub-Activity is changed there is no need to notify the Activity.

I just commented OnPropertyChanged() call in CurrentSubActivity property.
Here is the code

```
private int currentSubActivity;

    public int CurrentSubActivity
    {
        get { return currentSubActivity; }
        set
        {
            //OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSubActivity");
            this.currentSubActivity = value;

        }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone out there too :)

Comment: Maybe this works for you, but I don't think that this is a general answer that will help anybody else. There is no way the view will know that the property has changed if you remove the OnPropertyChanged call, which also breaks the MVVM pattern. If the UI is updating ok, for sure you are raising a notification somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind to the Text property in your comboboxes, try replacing:

```
 <ComboBox Text="{Binding CurrentActivity}"                                       
                                SelectedValuePath="ActivityID"                                        
                                DisplayMemberPath="ActivityName"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ActivitiesDataProvider}}"/>
```

with:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ActivitiesDataProvider}}"                                      
                                SelectedValuePath="ActivityID"                                        
                                DisplayMemberPath="ActivityName"
                                SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentActivity}"
                                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Same idea for the sub activities combobox. In general, for comboboxes use the SelectedItem and SelectedIndex properties. Also use IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem (depending on the type of ItemsSource.

By the way, you don't need to bind to the ID if you don't want to, you can bind directly to the whole object by using:

```
 SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

which will bind the value of the combobox to the selected item of the list, just keep it in synch with your VM using IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" (this applies if your VM is managing the list and knows which the selected item is).

Hope this helps you! Regards

Comment: Hannish, thank you for your help but it still didnt solve my issue, i still see empty list when i open the second combobox.

Comment: I see that in your second combobox you set DisplayMemberPath="SubActivityname"... are you sure spelling is correct? XAML is case sensitive and there is no intellisense help, so maybe try "SubActivityName"? Still you can tell if your binding is working if you can see a number of blank items when you open the combo, same as the number of subactivities.

Comment: Second combobox name is correct. I see same number of blank items for all the activities when i open the second combobox.

Comment: I you see a number of items it's just that you are not displaying the correct property, but the objects are there. Try displaying the ID, and again, check spelling just in case. You've almost got it!

Comment: I have verified everything, all the property names and column names, they all seem fine. Not sure why still there is an issue.
But however if i click another cell of other row, the corresponding SubActivities of second combox are populated for all the rows where Activity is selected in the first combobox.

Comment: You need to manage two events of the second combobox: PopupOpened and PopupClose (you can do that in code behind without breaking MVVM pattern). On PopupClose set the 2nd combo's itemssource to a list containing ALL subactivities of all activities. On PopupOpened filter that list to be the subactivities of the row's activity.